# Polymorphic deserialisation without the type info

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I need to deserialise a `JSON` payload. `JSON` payload contains a field `value` with 3 possible values.
It can be:

```
{
    ...,
    "value": {"X": 52, "Y": 56, "Z": 29}
}
```

or

```
{
    ....,
    "value": {"objectB":20}
}
```

or

```
{
    ...,
    "value": {"ObjectC":75}
}
```

I want to deserialise the field `value` without changing the `JSON` payload by adding `@type`. How to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question needs improvement. Please read: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Where do you want to add `@type` attribute? You do not want to change `JSON` payload so it means you want to deserialise `value` field by dynamic checking what it contains. Could you show what you already implemented and where do you have a problem? In case, you have some more info create a comment or edit your question.

Comment: @MichałZiober thak you for the reply ! Actually I can't change the Json payload !! the probleme is my "value" field does not contain any type property !! it contains only the properties of the three differents Objects ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC !! I need to deserialize the value field based on what it contains, if it contains a propA so deserialize it to ObjectA, if it contains propB ... !!